# drupal changing input html attribute "tabindex" in entityform module

Tags: forms, drupal, entity, customization

There is a module for creating HTML forms in Drupal CMS called "Entity Form". I created an Entity Form with two text boxes and one text area. 
how can i custom input's HTML attributes? i want to change the "tab index" attribute of these 3 inputs.

for example now there is:

```
<textarea tabindex="1"></textarea>
```

i want to change it to:

```
<textarea tabindex="3"></textarea>
```

i tried to find my input's name in module's files for customization but i didn't find anything.

i prefer to do it by Drupal itself interface. i want to find any other way,if it wasn't possible.